# I‘m get confused with super() usage

Tags: java, parent-child, parent, extend

I know super() is used to retrieve the instance variables from parent class, but when I saw the codes as follow:

```
public class novel extends literature {
private String title;
private String writer;
public novel(String title)
{
    super("novel");
    this.title = title;
    this.writer = "Unknow";
}
public novel(String title, String writer)
{
    super("novel");
    this.title = title;
    this.writer = writer;
}
public String getInfo()
{
    return getGenre() + "\nTitle: " + title + "\nWriter: " + writer;
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    novel n = new novel("The devil wears prada", "Lauren Weisberger");
    System.out.println(n.getInfo());
}

}
```

When I saw this: super("novel");  I get very confuse, how come the child class name can be put in the super method? 
And I don't know why `this.writer = "unknown";` is here for what? Why don't it just set it to be writer?

Sorry for throwing so many questions to you guys, but will appreciate a lot for any solutions.

**I'm sorry guys i still did not totally get why it used super("novel")? If we say novel here is a string, but then why we use that string which has the same name as "novel class"?**

Comment: Small hint: you should type names of classes with big letters acoring to best practises in Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`super ("novel")` means that you pass a String as argument for the constructor of the parent class. 
`this.writer = "Unknow"` means that you pass the String value `"Unknow"` to a member of the current class instance. You could also pass eg. "Mark Twain", the writer's variable value will then be "Mark Twain".

For more information http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

#### Example

```java
//Parentclass

public class Book {

private String genre;
private String isbn;

//As you can see we have two constructors.

//The first with only one argument
public Book (String genre)
    this.genre = genre;
}


//The second one with two arguments
public Book (String genre, String isbn) {
    this.genre = genre;
    this.isbn = isbn;
}

}

//subclass
class Novel extends Book{

public Novel(String isbn)
   
   
   super("novel", isbn);
   //super() has now two arguments, because we are calling the second constructor
   //which has two args. 
   //Now, in the parent class members genre = "novel" and isbn equals the value passed in the
   //child constructor.
   //This is the same as using the parent constructor inner body in this constructor. 
   //Normally the parent constructor gets overwritten on inheritance. 
   //But super makes its possible to use the parent constructor. 


}
```

For more examples [check this super() documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

Comment: But i tut super() that the bracket should only contain variables from parent class? and this string has same name as the child class name, it doesn't matter?

Comment: super() means that you pass arguments to the parent class constructor. So if parent(String) is the parent constructor, super(String) would pass a String to parent constructor. It doesn't matter if the String value is the same as the class name.

Comment: Emmm, but my book says super() is to retrieve constructors from parent, concepts kinda get me confused.

Comment: I posted an example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your super() keyword question.

Here i want to explain something and for easy understanding i am spawning a new example.

```
class foo
{
  foo(int t)
  {
  }
}

class bar extends foo
{
  bar()
  {
  }
}

class test
{
  public static void main(String gg[])
  {
    bar b=new bar();
  }
}
```

Above code will give you a compilation error. The reason behind the error is when object of class "b" is created that constructor of "b" will run. And from that constructor compiler implicitly places a call for base constructor, Like below code

```
b()
{
super();
}
```

Now if you introduced zero parameter constructor in foo class than this code will run without a problem.

```
class foo
{
  foo()
  {
  }

  foo(int t)
  {
  }
}

class bar extends foo
{
  bar()
  {     
  }
}

class test
{
  public static void main(String gg[])
  {
    bar b=new bar();
  }
}
```

In java compiler if no constructor is provided by programmer than compiler places a zero parameter constructor in class. And if programmer provide any constructor than compiler doesn't provide any constructor. Hope you got the answer.

Regarding your second question about this keyword. Yeah! for sure you can not place 'this' keyword. But it is good to place 'this' keyword to distinguish between class variable and local variable.
For your information here is the definition of 'this' pointer.
To every non static method of the class a this pointer is provided by compiler, 'this' pointer stores the address of the object for which method is being called. If you didn't got anything or need to know more ping me in comment.

Answer (score 0):

1. most probably, getGenre() method was implemented in parent class such as;

   ```
   class literature {
       private String genre;
       public literature(String genre) {
           this.genre = genre;
       }
       public String getGenre() {
           return this.genre;
       }}
   ```
2. there are two-way in order to create an instance for this sample. if you have both title and writer, no problem, but you have only title but no idea about writer, this creates an instance with writer "unknown".

Answer (score -1):

```
public novel(String title, String writer)
{
    super("novel");
    this.title = title;
    this.writer = writer;
}
```

The `super("novel");` calls the `literature` class's contructor with one parameter.

The `this.writer = "Unknow";` sets the novel object's writer attribute to "Unknow", because this constructor don't get the writer parameter, only the title.

Maybe you can write this, instead of the code above:

```
public novel(String title)
    {
        this(title, "Unknow"); // calls the constructor with two parameters
    }
```

Edit: Thanks for the help, i just copy-pasted it, and i forget to delete the super() call.

Comment: If you leave out the `super(novel)`, however, it will work just fine (and still call the super constructor, as that's the first thing the other constructor does).

Comment: But why super("novel") calls the literature class instead of using super()?

Comment: in the literature class there is a constructor with one parameter which sets the type of a literature, i think